# Como obtener la suma de un listview en android studio?

Tags: android, android-listview

A la fecha he logrado ir agregando elementos a mi lista, pero no conozco el método para que en un textview se me refleje el valor total de mi lista, tengo el código fuente por si alguien quiere probarlo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> telefonos;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador1;
    private ListView lv1;
    private EditText et1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        telefonos=new ArrayList<String>();
        telefonos.add("50");
        telefonos.add("50");
        telefonos.add("100");
        adaptador1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,telefonos);
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv1.setAdapter(adaptador1);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        lv1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final int posicion=i;

                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialogo1.setTitle("¡ Atención !");
                dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Borrar el registro ?");
                dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
                dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                        telefonos.remove(posicion);
                        adaptador1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.show();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void agregar(View v) {
        telefonos.add(et1.getText().toString());
        adaptador1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        et1.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: En el momento en que cargas tu ListView, puedes barrerlo para traer el valor que deseas y luego asignarlo al TextView. Comparte el código para revisarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido Cesar!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Agrega tu código por favor Cesar y trata de aportar mas detallles..

Comment: Les comparto el código, lo que deseo hacer es obtener la suma de los valores de mi lista,

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres obtener el número total de elementos que tienes en una lista y, considerando que la variable que contiene tu lista se llama `listView`, podrías usar el siguiente código:

```
int total = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
```

el cual te devolverá el número de elementos que contenga la lista.

Si quisieras que el valor estuviera reflejado en un `TextView`, entonces simplemente tendrías que agregar ese valor al mismo.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tuTextView);
textView.setText("" + total);
```

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo?